# What content type to set for ASP/ASPX file upload?

Tags: asp.net, web, iis

I want to know what HTTP header `Content-Type:`  to set, when uploading ASP/ASPX files to an IIS web server?

For PHP, it is `application/x-php`, so my guess would be `application/x-asp`, however I cannot find any sources that confirm this, e.g. checked http://www.asptutorial.info/sscript/ContentType.html.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such MIME type for .aspx files as such, if the content is HTML, you should put it as `text/html`, as .aspx files for clients are the same as a ordinary HTML file.

The only MIME for .asp is `text/asp`.

Comment: Are you sure text/asp shouldn't also be used for .aspx? What is your source?

Comment: @Shuzheng Also, an ASPX page streams text/html to the browser, so you can use it flawlessly

Comment: Thanks! Are MIME types standardized or are they created on a "per-need" basis?

Comment: Both, but the official authority that standardizes MIME is called Internet Assigned  Numbers Authority (IANA), which also publicates them. But you can handle a MIME yourself depending on the platform you're using to develop and publish your server/website (of course, it has to be approved).

IANA : https://www.iana.org/
IANA Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority

Answer (score 2):

There are many of them available throughout the web: I used to have mine too, until I found [this great GitHub project](https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap) that covers a gigantic amount of them: it also includes an efficient and deterministic two-way mapping, so you can also use it the other way around (retrieve the extension from a given MIME type).

I think this file help you:

[MimeTypeMap](https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap/blob/master/src/MimeTypes/MimeTypeMap.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace MimeTypes
{
    public static class MimeTypeMap
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IDictionary<string, string>> _mappings = new Lazy<IDictionary<string, string>>(BuildMappings);
        private static IDictionary<string, string> BuildMappings()
        {
            var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
                #region Big freaking list of mime types
                {".323", "text/h323"},
                {".3g2", "video/3gpp2"},
                {".3gp", "video/3gpp"},
                {".3gp2", "video/3gpp2"},
                {".3gpp", "video/3gpp"},
                .
                .
                .
                .
                {"video/x-dv", ".dv"},
                {"video/x-la-asf", ".lsf"},
                {"video/x-ms-asf", ".asf"},
                {"x-world/x-vrml", ".xof"},
                #endregion

                };

            var cache = mappings.ToList(); // need ToList() to avoid modifying while still enumerating

            foreach (var mapping in cache)
            {
                if (!mappings.ContainsKey(mapping.Value))
                {
                    mappings.Add(mapping.Value, mapping.Key);
                }
            }

            return mappings;
        }

        public static string GetMimeType(string extension)
        {
            if (extension == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("extension");
            }

            if (!extension.StartsWith("."))
            {
                extension = "." + extension;
            }

            string mime;

            return _mappings.Value.TryGetValue(extension, out mime) ? mime : "application/octet-stream";
        }

        public static string GetExtension(string mimeType)
        {
             return GetExtension(mimeType, true);
        }

        public static string GetExtension(string mimeType, bool throwErrorIfNotFound)
        {
            if (mimeType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("mimeType");
            }

            if (mimeType.StartsWith("."))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Requested mime type is not valid: " + mimeType);
            }

            string extension;

            if (_mappings.Value.TryGetValue(mimeType, out extension))
            {
                return extension;
            }
            if (throwErrorIfNotFound)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Requested mime type is not registered: " + mimeType);
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful! Do you know if MIME types are standardized?

Comment: What exactly you means about MIME types are standardized?

Comment: They they are defined by some institution or organization.

Comment: There's no such MIME type for aspx or another web serving the anatomy of these is `text/html` also you can test your self with code I send to you and get the MIME of your requested then add to your MIME list